# Background Colour of Text

Tags: html, css

I want to change only the background color of the text i.e in my case the background of ${keyword}. But the code changes the background color of the entire input box.

th correspondsto thymeleaf. I am using spring boot.
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
corresponding CSS code:

```css
.container {

   display: table; /* keep the background color wrapped tight */
       margin: 0px auto 0px auto; /* keep the table centered */
       padding:5px;font-size:20px;background-color:green;color:blue;
}
```

```html
<input class="container" type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" size="50" th:value="${keyword}" required/>
```

What will be the correct code so that only the background of the text would be colored?

Comment: What does " background of the text" mean?

Comment: Basically you can't. The input is the element, the text is not and so cannot be selected separately from the input..

Comment: @Shanie   I don't want to change the background-color of the entire page. Just I want to change the background-color of the portion where the text is written.

Comment: Are you using the class "container" anywhere else in your html

Comment: No. In the input tag only.

Comment: Then the css you have should work. It will set the background to green and the text will be blue. If you use ".container" somewhere else that element will be green as well.